# How can I insert a dash separated string into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have this string as my input string:

```
12345-45678-543245
```

So in my database table I want to insert these dash separated strings as followed:

```
   part_id  |  Part numbers
------------------------------
   1        |     12345
   2        |     45678
   3        |    543245
```

I have no idea how to do this? Maybe some hints and advices would help me.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Hard for me to distinguish input having dash then separately save them and have no idea how to do it

Comment: two things to do: explode your string and then prepare the statement for the multiple insert in database.

Comment: `$input="12345-45678-543245"; $data = explode('-',$input); save $data to database`

Comment: how to accept ? I will  ? sorry I was new in stackoverflow I just registered today

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano ^ Click on the link in my last comment, there you see how you can accept any answer

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano Before you now try to accept all answers. You can only accept one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) your INSERT statement and then loop through your [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)'d input and insert the values into your db.

```
<?php

    $input = "12345-45678-543245";
    $arr = explode("-", $input);

    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "myDBName";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (`part_id`, `Part numbers`) VALUES(?, ?)");
        foreach($arr as $k => $v)
            $stmt->execute([($k+1), $v]);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string  = '12345-45678-543245';
$array = explode('-',$string);
Foreach($array as $arr){
    //Here add to database...
}
```

But that is very simple PHP...
Please visit php.net for more info ¬.¬'

Comment: thanks! yes forgot to search first before asking questions here

Answer (score 1):

You can explode your string to separate it into sections.

```
<?php
$string = "12345-45678-543245"

$parts = explode("-", $string);

$p0 = $parts[0];  //12345
$p1 = $parts[1];  //45678
$p2 = $parts[2];  //543245
?>
```